# Flutter "Execution failed for task ':printing:parseDebugLocalResources'"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to write a program in Flutter using a printer and PDF package but it does not work and shows the message error as shown below:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':printing:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':printing:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

and here is my pubsec.yaml dependencies:
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
printing: ^5.0.3
pdf: ^3.10.4

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2